# How can I implement CSS Cache Busting with JSF outputStylesheet?

Tags: java, css, jsf, cache-control, browser-cache

In JSF page templates I use this code to include a CSS resource:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="mystyles.css"  />
```

The usual way to implement CSS cache busting would be to add a version parameter, like `v=123`, however this is not supported in outputStyleSheet:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="mystyles.css?v=123"  />
```

will cause a JSF1064 warning and the CSS will not be found.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not possible without overridding the `StylesheetRenderer` (assuming you're on Mojarra). It does indeed not take the query string into account. However, as a (temporary) workaround it's good to know that it is valid to include the CSS using CSS' own `@import` rule inside `<h:outputStyleSheet>`.

```
<h:outputStylesheet target="head">
    @import url('css/mystyles.css?v=123')
</h:outputStylesheet>
```

You might want to post an [enhancement request](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES) to the Mojarra boys to take this into account in future releases.

Comment: @banter: better use resource library versioning. See also bottom of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used/11988418#11988418

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to avoid to rename directories. From JSP, I am used to define scripts version via maven version propagated to request. So it does not look like that there is a simple solution in JSF.

Comment: @banter: Create a custom resource handler then.

Comment: What about not to use 'h' tags and write just html?