# href="RES_NOT_FOUND" using h:outputStylesheet

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2, stylesheet

I am creating **multi-language** web based application using JSF 2.0.

For css earlier I was using

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="setFontForAll.css"/>
```

and inside CSS file I had

```
font-size: #{msg['myDir'].contains('LTR')?'10pt':'14pt'};
                                           ^^^     ^^^
                                          English Arabic
```

However due to CSS caching, same CSS file is there and I am getting font as 10pt continously even if I choose Arabic.

Hence I added time after CSS.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="setFontForAll.css?#{language.myTimeinMill}"/>
```

However when I use this, all my CSS goes for toss... I see default page setup (no css is getting invoked)

When I see view source, I get `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Note : I am using JSF 2.0**

---

I am also printing `#{language.myTimeinMill}` inside body and everytime I see different time.

Comment: Are you sure `setFontForAll.css` is in `<web-root>/resources/css/` ?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie : yes its there... when I remove `?#{language.myTimeinMill}` it works...

Comment: This answer could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6308870/354831

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie : When I use `<h:outputStylesheet target="head">
    @import url('css/mystyles.css?v=123')
</h:outputStylesheet>`, I see error as `The required attribute name is missing`

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: Actually I was using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161139/changes-in-css-files-are-not-reflected-after-deployment)

Comment: I think this was a good way, any reason changing?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie : Earlier I thought that would not work in jsf 2.0. as in jsf 2.0 <h:outputStylesheet  works...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie : Any idea how to pass two parameters here? I want to say `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/setFontForAll.css?ln=css&#{language.myTimeinMill}" />` but & is giving error... what should we use instead of & in jsf?

Comment: JSF 1.X, 2.X, etc only render HTML/CSS/JavaScript content and I don't think that will change for a long time :)

Comment: Change `&` for `&amp;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see is using the plain `<link>` tag.

There is no possibility by using `<h:outputStylesheet />` to add a parameter in the URL. One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6308870/354831) on this subject **doesn't work** anymore on JSF 2.0 :

```
<h:outputStylesheet target="head" name="blank.css">
    @import url('css/setFontForAll.css?version=#{language.myTimeinMill}')
</h:outputStylesheet>
```

It returns a message :

> com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ScriptStyleBaseRenderer
>   encodeChildren INFO: outputScript with "name" attribute and nested
>   content.  Ignoring nested content.

That said, I suggest **this solution** :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/setFontForAll.css?ln=css&amp;version=#{language.myTimeinMill}" />

<ui:fragment rendered="#{msg['myDir'].contains('LTR')}">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/setFontOverride.css?ln=css&amp;version=#{language.myTimeinMill}" />
</ui:fragment>
```

Comment: This is working, but now I am facing another problem. In CSS file I have `font-size: #{msg['myDir'].contains('LTR')?'10pt':'14pt'};`. i.e. if the layout is LTR (English) font size is 10pt and if layout is RTL size is 14pt.... but when I use link, it don't recognize `#{msg['myDir']` statement... **MEANS I have to make two css file?**

Comment: :( I have posted question... let see if there is any solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892722/how-to-load-new-css-on-every-page

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all you need to do is create a folder under webapp/resources/css/mystyle.css where mystyle.css is your css file.

Then in your jsf file, just put

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/mystyle.css" />
```

JSF will knows and load your css file correctly without the RES_NOT_FOUND error.

PS. this has been tested with primefaces jsf 2.2